# Why does the EU not seem to pursue technological independence?

Tags: european-union, technology

Why does the European Union not seem to pursue technological independence?  While I am just a naïve citizen without deep insight, it seems to me that many technologies that seem critical to both our daily lives and national security are imported, and no longer developed in a visible manner within Europe.

Just think of computers, and what would happen if a country lost access to them.  The US, Russia, and several East Asian countries seem to have the capability to produce their own more-or-less competitive computer hardware if need be, but I am not aware of anything within Europe.  Not even (smart)phones are made there anymore. The parts of Nokia and Ericsson that could do this in the past are long gone.

Or think of one of the most critical tools we use every day: the internet search engine. The only search engines that actually get any use, and use their *own* technology, are again American, Russian or East Asian.

The same goes for social networks, which definitely aren't a technology we need, but could be deemed a national security issue. All the ones that are popular in Europe are controlled by American companies.  The EU seems to try to regulate how these companies handle private data, but will that ever truly prevent US government access to that data in practice?  Having citizens use local technology would be more secure.  There used to be popular country-specific social networks in Europe, but all that I knew of are now gone or irrelevant.

Why does the European Union seem to accept such huge technological dependence, mostly on the United States?  It would be naïve to think that relations could never worsen, even if the current disagreements may turn out to be only temporary.

Or am I incorrect about this?  Do EU countries actually have most of these technologies, even if in a latent form, not visible to consumers?  Or perhaps they do try to achieve technological independence but simply fail at it?

Comment: I'd say that your conclusion: 'EU doesn't do them, because they don't know how' is simply false. Perhaps EU simply doesn't pursue technological independence.

Comment: There was [Quaero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaero).

Comment: Who is this "European Union" you are talking about? The Comission? The European Council? The European Parliament? The major companies in Europe? The people of Europe? The member states of the EU? Which of these parties do you want to do what?

Comment: I am not sure if the premise of this question is even true. While Europe isn't that famous for IT products (even though it is home of some notable IT companies, like SAP for example), it is world leader in many areas of mechanical and electric engineering. The pharmaceutical sector is also worth mentioning. Fact is, in the 21st century, no country is really self-sufficient.

Comment: Although there are little or none strong competitors to companies such as Alphabet, Microsoft, or Amazon I wouldn't exactly call the EU a void for mass consumer digital technology. Spotify, ResearchGate, Mendeley, Skyscanner, Deezer, SoundCloud, Trivago, Booking.com, or even Skype or Shazam until recently (both were bought by US companies). Notice that although the EU is a big market it still suffers from scalability obstacles, most of them due to localization (language and regional differences). EU integration has gone far, but its still not that of a single country (not even close).

Comment: If by "European Union," you mean, the government, then part of your premise is false. While search engines, PCs, and social networks are all developed in the US, these are not government projects. They are companies founded by citizens, such as yourself.

Comment: The USA isn't technologically independent either. Almost all of its electronics are manufactured in factories in China.

Comment: To paraphrase Nietzsche, it would be good to do which you are able

Comment: @Communisty I am not sure how that came across as a *conclusion*. It's a question. There are no conclusions in there.

Comment: @MartinSchröder To have to look for some framework or organization before asking the question seems like putting the cart in front of the horse to me.  The countries within the geographical area of Europe have strong collaborations in many areas, and do plan for the future together to some extent. It seems to me that the various organizations that you mention are just means to this end, and not the reverse.  If you mean that what I ask is not possible because there is no existing framework for it, I can accept that if written in a well argued answer.

Comment: `Why does the EU not seem to pursue ...` You already stablish that as a fact, so it is a best a poorly worded question. And a minimal research will tell at least about [R&D programs](http://ec.europa.eu/programmes/horizon2020/en). Apart from that, a point that most answers avoid is answering *what could the EU do*. Even if you were to accept the premise that iPhones not being European is an issue, what should the EU do? Ban Apple? Tariffs? Put lots of funding into EU based competitors? Actions like these are likely to escalate into commercial wars and have other consequences...

Comment: Not enough rep to post an answer, but the simple answer to your question " Do EU countries actually have most of these technologies, even if in a latent form, not visible to consumers?" is yes. Yes they do. The knowledge, manpower and infrastructure needed to make a 'home grown' version of anything (from space faring rockets to nuclear bombs to search engines to social media) is readily available. It would be very bad economics for the EU member states to model their economy(s) on nationalist sentiment rather than sound economic theory, but if needs be, it can be done.

Comment: Oh and I forgot to mention - China isn't technologically independent, all its factories use equipment designed and sometimes built in the EU.

Comment: If anyone could, would it be a good idea to run around showing it to the world? Probably not... It would probably be kept as much secret as possible.

Comment: @MartinSchröder https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union in case you somehow missed it these last 70 years...

Comment: @TylerH I think he means it in the same sense as you would ask : "What do you mean it (some particular thing) would be """good""" for country X?". It could be good for many different people or groups: the citizens, the politicians, specific professions, big industry companies, economists, bankers, customs officials, tourism and hotels, police, the universities. But maybe for other of those groups it would be worse.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

The EU does pursue technological independence. For example, it has assembled its own satellite navigation system so that it does not have to rely on GPS and Glonass.

The EU develops a lot of military hardware (ships, jets, missiles, you name it). The EU also has its own space programme and the ability to put objects in orbit independently.

On the computing front, ARM is (for the moment) an EU company and ARM CPUs are the most common in the world. Europe has huge tech companies like Siemens and Philips.

The EU fined Google heavily for anti-competitive practices that were making it harder for EU companies to compete.

So the suggestion that Europe does not pursue technological independence is simply untrue.

Comment: "*ARM is (for the moment) an EU company*" depends on what you mean by "*EU company*". It's owned by a Japanese bank.

Comment: Other companies to add to the list: Ericsson (anyone has heard about that Bluetooth thing?), Siemens, Alcatel. Which have a not-so-potent line of end-consumer products, but that do really well in the infrastructure market. And of course, King of "Candy Crush" fame :-). It seems that the OP did not bother much with research.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes, although it was founded in the UK after it joined the EU and has existed for most of its life inside the EU. Even now it is based in and incorporated in the EU, at least until Brexit hits.

Comment: YOu should also add a description or reference to https://ec.europa.eu/info/research-and-innovation_en

Comment: @PeterTaylor SoftBank isn't really a bank.

Comment: @PeterTaylor In the event of an intentional conflict foreign ownership a technical capability can be changed through forced nationalization.

Comment: @SJuan76 don't forget Nokia that bought Alcatel-Lucent

Comment: @SJuan76 indeed, and EU car manufacturers too. Renault with EVs, Volvo and Audi with driving aids etc.

Comment: Galileo is an example being behind. The US (GPS), Russians (GLONASS), Chinese (COMPASS), and even Japanese (QZSS), all managed to get working systems before the EU can. On top of that, ARM is owned by the Japanese (SoftBank) and strictly in IP licensing. Unlike Intel, it's reliant on another company to complete the design and then fabricate it (IBM and AMD can do all but fabricate).

Comment: @user71659 your suggestion that the EU was "behind" implies that you think there was a race. There wasn't.

Comment: regarding electronics, there is STMicroelectronics, and Soitec keeping silicon fabs in France, partly to provide an EU source to its military clients. While it does not matter that much where consumer products are made, the bulk of military hardware is sourced locally.

Comment: @SJuan76 Another perfect example of EU losing out: while Ericsson developed the Bluetooth standard, it quickly lost any purpose for the company after smartphones killed their cell handset business. Ericsson's main role in Bluetooth today is their existing IP. Broadcom became the dominant supplier of Bluetooth chipsets because of the need for integration with Wi-Fi, followed by Cambridge Silicon Radio (now part of Qualcomm).

Answer (score 44):

It’s not only EU, there is no such thing as a technological independent state anymore. North Korea is the closest one to be. There are enterprises in US and Asia which manufacture nanotechnology, but they depend on world spanning supply chains. They need equipment from e.g. the Netherlands (ASML). ASML is dependent on components from Germany.

So no counties owns all piece of the puzzle to manufacture nanotechnology by its own. The cause for this is that the market for some components is too small to sustain a large number of enterprises. So we have few players which dominate their niche. Building everything by your own is not economical feasible and would cause you to fall behind in technology.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to mention ASML but you already did. Europe makes the machines that make computers (chips), basically.

Comment: *Some* of the equipment needed to make semiconductor devices ("chips") is made in Europe. While ASML has ~85% market share in its specific niche (with the balance left to Japanese companies Nikon and Canon), Applied Materials, Lam Research, and KLA-Tencore are examples of large American companies that also provide equipment to the semiconductor industry.

Answer (score 21):

Technological independence is a strategic military goal, not an economic one. One of the basic principles of economics is [comparative advantage](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/comparativeadvantage.asp), which says that trade will benefit both parties if there is a difference between the relative costs of producing different items (so if bread and biscuits cost X and 2X respectively in country A, and Y and 3Y in country B, then A should specialize in biscuits while B specializes in bread, regardless of the values of X and Y).

The EU is an economic organisation not a military one. It has no military goals, and in fact no military at all. Hence technological independence is not a factor in its thinking. It simply looks to increase the advantages of trade between its members.

The various nations that make up the EU each have their own military, and may well pay attention to the ways in which their military capabilities are dependent on other nations.

Comment: That is a very narrow vision of the EU. It has a common constitution, an EU citizen protocol, common (non-economical) policies, it's own parliament, governance and budget. It currently even has military and policing capabilities (just recently the EII was signed by 9 members - UK included -, and in 2017 PESCO was approved by 25 members). It's not a fully integrated nation, I agree, but it's not exactly NAFTA either. Your definition *"It simply looks to increase the advantages of trade between its members."* is way off target.

Comment: Energy, Environment, Health, Social sciences and humanities, Transport, etc are not military goals. See https://ec.europa.eu/info/research-and-innovation/research-area_en

Comment: The EU not having a military at all is just half-true. While there is no dedicated EU army, the militaries of the EU members cooperate in the [Common Security and Defence Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Security_and_Defence_Policy). A dedicated EU army is a topic which various EU politicians bring up again from time to time.

Comment: There's a [NATO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO) as well, which isn't the EU but of which most European countries are members.

Comment: @armatita the EU does not have a "common constitution". One was proposed but was subsequently rejected. EU law has primacy over Member State law, but generally not over each member states own constitution.

Comment: @Max With the Lisbon Treaty the [Charter of Fundamental Rights of the European Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charter_of_Fundamental_Rights_of_the_European_Union) became effectively legally binding within the boundaries of the treaties. It's true that it's not exactly the same system as other constitutions, but the EU is not exactly a single nation either. Nevertheless there are indeed ongoing efforts to make it compatible with national constitutions. Also there are many nations with somewhat irregular or inexistant constitutional treaty, UK included (for example).

Comment: @armatita Yes, I know. I agree on everything you said in your original comment except the constitution part. A constitution outlines the "principles according to which a nation, state, corporation, or the like, is governed". The Charter of Fundamental Rights does not do that, it only defines human rights. The closest we have to that is the Treaty of the Functioning of the European Union (TFEU). The Treaty of Lisbon contains much of the original content of the planned EU constition but only amended earlier treaties rather than replacing them altogether with a constition.

Comment: @Max Very well I won't insist, although I would argue that the charter is fully within the description that you gave for a constitution (I'm not sure what you mean by human rights; as I mentioned in my latest comment constitution documents vary a lot in scope, they don't need to strictly define judicial and executive powers and roles). But indeed the word "constitution" has been deliberately removed from the Lisbon treaty (likely to prevent new rejections).

Answer (score 19):

A full answer would probably take several books.

But in part it's a combination of economics and politics.

- On the economics side, manufacturing is too expensive in Europe (just like in US), due in large part to high labour costs, but also other costs. Which is why your phones and computer parts are mostly physically made in Asia.
- On the political - and as a consequence, economic - side, EU has far more regulation, taxes, and general environment that on average tends to be a little less welcoming to start-ups.

  It's easier and more potentially rewarding to be an entrepreneur in US than in Europe. No risk that you'll be taxed at 90% rate (as France tried to do recently). No difficult labour regulations making it impossible to fire bad workers, or to have people work overtime. Extra overhead for things like long parental leaves (which is good for parents and bad for start-ups).

Comment: China has even less extra overhead things than US. In the US companies can't employ children even to do simple manual tasks (which is good for children and bad for start-ups).

Comment: "On the economics side, manufacturing is too expensive in Europe" - but manufacturing is not research & development. The countries with the least labor costs are not known as the research powerhouses of the world. So I fail to see why this should be a reason for technological disadvantage. Taxes and more restrictive labor regulation might be a point, but regulations throughout the EU are very different without any of the states being technologically on par with the US. And Israel harbors many high-tech companies and still has quite high regulations and taxations.

Comment: @Communisty - in China, it's harder to start a business unless you're politically connected.

Comment: @Thern - the question explicitly mentioned "making" things, not just R&D

Comment: (-1) In fact, Europe has a striving start-up scene, regulation varies a lot from one country to another and is far from the main driver of start-up success. But the implied notion that technology = start-ups is silly to be begin with.

Comment: @user4012 "the question explicitly mentioned "making" things, not just R&D" - I understood the question differently, but if the concrete manufacturing is meant, you are right with the high labor costs.

Comment: @Relaxed: If you don't want to look at startups, feel free to look at the other side. The top 10 technology companies by market value aren't European either.

Comment: @Communisty: So, growth-wise we have China > USA > EU, and regulation-wise we have China < USA < EU. I'm not disagreeing with your observation, but it just seems to strengthen the point made, even though I sense that's not your intent.

Comment: @MSalters Apple and Samsung as an example of the power of light regulation? Please... Not that I see much value in that indicator either. At least the startup thing, while simplistic and completely off-base, had some surface plausibility.

Comment: @Relaxed - Yes, Apple (the original one, that built stuff out of a garage) is. Imagine if there was a regulation that you can't build PCs in a residential zone, for whatever (environmental or political) reasons. BAM. One more reason that Apple happening might not have happened. Or imagine there were regulations prohibiting stuff that iTunes did, under RIAA pressure. BAM. No modern Apple (because their commercial success was based largely on iTunes)

Comment: @user4012 The first Apple was very close to being bankrupt. On the other hand, the current one profited mightily from copyright laws (killing the free competition) and other intellectual property rights (instrumental in protecting its own assets and brand). In other words: It played the game right and benefited from a specific set of regulations, hotly contested between equally powerful players (e.g. Apple and Google vs. recording majors). Not that there is anything wrong with that but a case study in the virtue of the lack of regulation and the success of a small disruptive player it is not.

Comment: @Relaxed - you are confusing late apple (AFTER it made tons of money off of iPhone) and earlier one, sorry. And first Apple didn't get bankrupt till much later, when Microsoft ate their lunch. They were nowhere close to startup by that time, just a failed company.

Comment: @user4012 Exactly but I am not confusing anything. They were a failed company, hardly a success story. They then became the largest company by market value (the original argument I was responding to, remember?) And they didn't do that in their garage but much later, among other reasons thanks the regulations I pointed out. It's indeed much later but that's what's relevant here.

Comment: Forbes disagrees with your assertion that it's better to be an entrepreneur in the USA than in Europe. In fact, of all the countries to choose between, they've _repeatedly_ picked a notorious "socialist" one, with high taxes and strong labor rights. In 2015, they wrote: "Denmark is one of the most entrepreneurial countries in the world. The government streamlines the startup process with only four procedures needed to start a new business and at minimal costs. The regulatory climate is also one of the most efficient." http://surl.dk/heh Most recently, the UK ranked #1, the US #12.

Comment: What happens in the US when your entrepreneurial plan fails? What happens in the EU?

Comment: @immibis - depends on EU country. Since none are running UBI at the moment, pretty much the same thing, at large.

Comment: @user4012 If you have the money to build up a high tech facility you can easily have the money to buy political connections

Answer (score 11):

I'd challenge the premise: The EU (countries) would *love* to be able to have all strategically important industries at home, but they just don't, and they can't. The economic currents of a globalized economy are beyond the power of nations or alliances, even the U.S. or Europe. They are also elusive to planning. The smart phone revolution was not a strategic plan, at least not by governments or commissions. Facebook wasn't, either.

The E.U does strategically support research in perceived key fields, like the Human Brain Project and [others](http://ec.europa.eu/programmes/horizon2020/en/h2020-section/fet-flagships). The results sometimes do not meet the expectations.

"National security" is a soft term, but even the U.S. are certainly more dependent on Asian chip makers than they would like. The U.S. cannot control the globalized economy any more than the E.U: You may remember Obama's [futile support for Solyndra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solyndra) or perhaps the [Pulitzer Prize winning New York Times article](http://www.pulitzer.org/article/how-apple-makes-iphones-and-why-it-happens-overseas) about the iPhone jobs which are not coming back (there are simply not enough skilled workers available in the U.S. to produce them).

It would be equally impossible and futile to try to keep perceived key industries in Europe alive, apart from the select few with immediate military use: Europe can build ships, land vehicles, aircraft and rockets, and has its own nuclear fuel cycle. (I know it all sounds terribly old-fashioned, but it still kills people.) Some of them are profitable, some of them aren't, and all of them have been subsidized at times and would be subsidized again should the need arise. Black coal was deemed a strategic asset (for steel — read: war ship/tank — production) and is only now being phased out in Germany. Food is considered a strategic asset and consequently the European food production will be sustained at all cost.

One word to your search engine. Programming a search engine is not rocket science; I believe I could program one for you in a few weeks which would work reasonably well (i.e, let you find stuff). What's harder is to get the ranking algorithm perfect and then earn money with it by serving fitting ads to your viewers. I wouldn't be amazed if the logic weeding out link farms, undue ranking optimization and fakes needs more code than the actual ranking core.

Larry and Sergey went from a trivial web crawler to a first back-link ranking algorithm [in a few months in 1996.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Google#Beginning)

Comment: As a counterpoint... sure, a search engine today is easy: Hadoop and MapReduce. But, it was not easy, nor obvious, in the early 1990's when Page and Brin came up with what was for that day a fairly radical idea. Nor did Google take off quickly... it took eight to ten years for Google to rise from startup to search and advertising giant... I remember using Google in the late 90's as an occasional option. There are skilled workers in the US to make iPhones, apple just doesn't want to pay them when they can hire Asians for far less. Might cut into their billions of cash.

Comment: @tj1000 Did you read the article? I'd recommend it. Quotes: "For technology companies, the cost of labor is minimal" ... "What U.S. plant can find 3,000 people overnight [...]?" ...  "Another critical advantage for Apple was that China provided engineers at a scale the United States could not match. Apple’s executives had estimated that about 8,700 industrial engineers were needed [...] it would take as long as nine months to find that many qualified engineers in the United States. In China, it took 15 days." ... “They’re
good jobs, but the [U.S.] doesn’t have enough to feed the demand,”

Comment: @tj1000 With respect to the search engines: The idea behind google was surely brilliant, but it is not difficult to reproduce on a basic level. The question was just whether the E.U. is technologically dependent on google's search engine; the answer is, they aren't. They *may* be dependent on the computing infrastructure of google and amazon (e.g. my son's public school is basically run on google services), even though some data centers are in Northern Europe because it is nice and cold and yet well developed. Still, creating a google/amazon cloud equivalent in Europe would take a few years.

Answer (score 7):

Because the problems you describe are not as serious as you think, and not as likely.

Computers may not be a great example, because [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_computer_exports) puts EU countries at 3rd, 6th, 8th, 13th and 15th for computer exports.

However, even if the EU tore down every computer factory that they have, then the situation still wouldn't be that bad.

To address the likelihood of a problem. The EU still would have a diverse range of countries to purchase computers from. Ultimately, countries are not going to refuse to sell computers to the EU unless they are close to war. North Korea imports computers, despite a wide range of sanctions on them. China and the USA are #1 and #2 for computer exports. If the EU alienated one of these two superpowers, they are likely to find the other power is happy to treat them as a close friend.

What is more likely is that the EU may face trade policies that make imported computers a bit more expensive. This is a much more likely, but much less serious problem.

And in terms of the severity of the problem, I think you are overestimating how difficult it would be for the EU to start computer manufacturing if it became necessary. The EU has great primary, secondary and tertiary education, a lot of money, an established manufacturing sector and knowledge of how modern computers are made. If computer scarcity became a problem, the EU would give money to the highly educated and skilled workforce, and tell them to solve the problem.

All the computer exporters know that the EU could create a new manufacturing sector (or revive an old one) if they wanted to. That keeps the EU's trading partners honest - they know that if they try to charge too much, or refuse to sell products, then that would encourage the EU to create a competitor for them.

Comment: The glaring problem in this analysis is that there's barely such a thing as a "computer" - what really matters are the constituent technologies, particularly the longest lead ones like current-generation semiconductor fabs that take billions of dollars and years to spin up.  As pointed out elsewhere, a number of key IP design houses and chip companies are EU based, and there's no shortage of software talent either.  It becomes a question more of keeping a not-that-far-from-current fab on-shore, which one of the other answers alleges is the case.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Billions sounds like a big number, but for the EU, as a contingency if trading has broken down such that they cannot import semiconductors from anywhere else in the world, I would hardly call it significant.

Comment: It's significant to do in the absence of pressing need - there are really only a handful of latest generation fabs in the world.  The problem is that if the need is pressing, you don't have *time* to build it and spin it up.  And hypothetically, in an economic dispute, the moment you decide to and commit to the project, those choking off the supply would re-open the flood gates until you give up at huge loss, then shut them again...

Answer (score 4):

Not necessarily true... Airbus has become a top competitor in a tough and unforgiving tech market: airliners. While longtime airliner makers Douglas and Lockheed folded and left the industry, Airbus entered and thrived. Europe turns out some first rate weapons systems, which is about as tech heavy as it gets. Rolls Royce is a top competitor in the very technical gas turbine engine market... though they won't be with the EU much longer.

One area the EU has fallen short in is software. The only major software today from the EU that I can think of is the German SAP firm, a major player in ERP software.

Almost all of the major software in use today comes out of the US. Databases, open source, HTML and the web browser (Tim Berners-Lee in the UK contributed the web server), text messaging, social media, mobile computing, cloud computing, all were originally designed and implemented in the US. Programming languages are based on English, because almost all were created in the US.

Most of those endeavors were either entrepreneur created or entrepreneur driven. Due to lower levels of regulation, it's a lot easier for an individual or a small group to get their idea to market with enough profit to drive further development in the US than the heavily regulated EU.

One might argue that mobile computing was started by a corporation - Apple - but Apple was being run by a visionary entrepreneur at that time, the same entrepreneur who started Apple. Normally, a major corporation would never have made that sort of investment in such a radical idea, but Jobs ran the company at that time, and was in a position to push it through. For further evidence of this, look at the technical lethargy Apple has slipped into since Jobs died.

Comment: Tim Berners-Lee did not just "contribute the web server" but drafted the HTML language and HTTP protocol to transmit it. The seminal programming language Algol was an American-European collaboration. And the smartphone has many mothers and fathers (read [*The One Device*](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/06/19/books/review/one-device-secret-history-iphone-brian-merchant.html)), more than a few Europeans among them (the Finnish [Nokia Communicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_Communicator) was one of the first smart phones).

Comment: MySQL is a European software, Qt is, Linux was developed by some student in Finnland.

Comment: The Python programming language was developed in the Netherlands by a dutchman and is in use all over the globe. However, if you take a close look into the history and origins of _any_ software product you will find contributions from people all around the world. Let's not forget that most of the giants in the industry have a _very_ international outlook, both in their staffing as in where they operate and develop their products. It truly is a 'human endavour'.

Comment: @MartinSchröder some would say that 'some student' is an understatement -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus_Torvalds

Comment: @Communisty: How so? Looks like a completely accurate description of him at that time.

Comment: You're substantially underestimating the European contribution (including key foundership and leadership) to many thoroughly international software products and projects that you mistakenly identify uniquely with the US.

Comment: What I see a lot when I look at major FOSS projects, is stuff starting in Europe, but moving to the US. Linux was created at a Finnish university, but linus moved to the USA soon after graduation and after going through several jobs there, is now employed by a US based foundation. Python's creator moved to the US and again after going through several jobs there, is now employed by Microsoft while his project is associated with a US based foundation. Mysql was bought out by Sun, through it's creator stayed in Europe and eventually went on to start a fork of the project he had sold off.

Comment: Linux was a copy of Unix, which was developed at Bell Labs in the US, initially as the basis for a telephone switching network. Linus Torvalds didn't come up with Linux from scratch. He copied what Bell Labs had done 30 years before.

Answer (score 3):

I guess there's no benefit to pursuing "independence" like that. IMO the question is like asking, "Why doesn't Bill Gates mow his own grass? What would happen, if he lost access to a gardener?"

I gather from the news, for example, that what keeps Iran from having military nuclear weapons is [centrifuges](https://www.google.fr/search?q=iran+centrifuges) -- i.e. that you need a lot of good centrifuges to separate fissile Uranium. IMO a country like Germany for example isn't officially 'a nuclear power', but looking at its industries I think it would obviously be able to manufacture any tools like that (i.e. like centrifuges) that it might ever need.

Your mentioning "Facebook" implies to me that you're picking the (few?) areas in which 'American' companies dominate, and asking, "Why doesn't Europe compete?" I presume that Facebook is trivial technology: merely a web site, a famous name, and users. Everyone these days (i.e. Europeans too) knows how to write "web-scale" sites. The leading cloud providers (Amazon, Google, Microsoft) are OK or leading-edge at what they do, but IMO what they do is just (or is mostly only) a matter of money -- i.e. anyone could do that, if they had to and were willing to pay more, to do it more expensively than buying off-the-shelf from the incumbents (e.g. governments presumably do run their own relatively expensive, private, secure, computer networks and servers).

Also Google for example has development offices in Europe -- in Switzerland, and so on. My guess is that if (hypothetically) America ever went dark, off the grid, the fundamental technology or know-how is well distributed globally. If it isn't commercially viable to compete against Google -- and they have a lot of trade secrets, and own a lot of assets (hardware, intellectual property, and human resources) -- but even so IMO it would be technologically feasible to deploy a inferior national-scale replacement implementation in the event of  a national emergency.

IMO there's limited national advantage to "owning" something like Facebook (one could argue that it obviously didn't do America any good). Web and software companies (like Amazon or Uber) have a bit of first-mover advantage, and spend a lot of money (i.e. are unprofitable) to get there -- usually private money, rather than government subsidies and investments -- but even so have local competition which could take over if the 'American' company disappeared.

The internet itself is distributed --- a country can be cut off from others and still have its own web sites: which is maybe more important for countries like China (has a firewall and censorship, and ambitions of its own) and Russia (may face sanctions).

If the governments (e.g. EU) are going to spend money on subsidising any industry, there are other industries that are more "strategic" than you ones you mentioned -- e.g. the national power grid; public transportation (including trains) and roads; agriculture (including "food security"); national health (medical research and deployment); national education; the telecommunications grid; the tax office and the police force; etc.

I'd argue too that laws and regulations (political science) are an important technology, and are the proper domain (sphere of interest and influence) of national governments, and something which the EU does pursue "independently".

And Europe does invest some in far-out R&D -- outer space; nuclear fusion; CERN; not to mention military (and medical and industrial) devices.

And countries do (to a certain extent) maintain some independent social media (propaganda outlets) too -- e.g. the newspapers, TV stations, radio broadcasters aren't all foreign, they may have some indigenous movie production too, and any number of non-English-language web sites and/or government web sites that you won't have heard of.

**Do EU countries actually have most of these technologies, even if in a latent form, not visible to consumers? Or perhaps they do try to achieve technological independence but simply fail at it?**

I think they have technological ability.

And that what they don't have is the political will to spend national money, to subsidise "private industry", to try to ensure that their "national" companies become world-leaders in every industry.

Some of "their" "national" companies are (already, naturally) world leaders in their industries (Rolls Royce for jet engines).

I guess they have neither the (financial) capacity nor the political will required to subsidise (or inflate) an ambition to be "world-class" (or world leaders) in every industry.

That's more-or-less true of every country, I think -- every country has some industries or market niches in which it's out-competed in the world market.

Comment: "implies to me that you're picking the (few?) areas in which 'American' companies dominate" No, I was picking the few that were visible to me, while admitting that I probably don't see the whole story. Also, for all examples I showed, both Russia and some Asian countries (China, Korea, etc.) are competitive.

Comment: As for Facebook, that part of the question was motivated by these technologies being a huge national security issue. Have you been to China recently?  Look at the power of Tencent there, the staggering amount of data they collect about everyone, how they're cooperate with the Chinese government (e.g. part in development of social credit). Now look at how they push the same technologies abroad (e.g. WeChat in India), and you will immediately see all of Facebook/Google/Twitter, etc. being American-controlled in a very different light.

Comment: I meant that I didn't see Facebook as very high-technology: so it's not that the EU lacks "**technological**" know-how or independence. I expect that national security agencies already see what we post on Facebook if ever they want to -- e.g. via **legislative** control (e.g. a court order to the user database), or other means (surveillance of the nation's telecom data). But if you wanted to ask about the EU's response (or lack of it) to the fact of Facebook's user database being weaponized as a tool for political control, you might ask (or might have asked) a more specific question IMO.

Comment: Sentences in the question like, "Just think of computers, and what would happen if a country lost access to them" had me thinking you were asking about nations' preserving a capacity to produce strategic-important technology locally; rather than being a question about privacy, about social media as an instrument of political control, etc.

Comment: The Iranian uranium centrifuges actually were made by a German company. (Or at least their control systems. [Stuxnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuxnet), the virus which was supposed to sabotage the Iranian nuclear program, was specifically targeting Siemens S7-300 SCADA systems)

Comment: "capacity to produce strategic-important technology locally" Yes, that was my question. You are right, I should probably have left out the Facebook part. I won't edit the question now as there are already too many answers, some discussing that part as well.